# Unable to change variable by function

Tags: javascript, web

I can't figure out why my function getID() isn't changing the galleryID variable.
Any help appreciated!

```
var img;
var gallery = {0: "CIBf-QSFMZD", 1: "CFfihZ0BxQo", 2: "CDUNuwvgB7N", 3: "CByDTh8gUWa", 4: "CB3i7NoA-IK", 5: "CKSEJG9rlJn", 6: "CEHrD8yAFXn", 7: "CIY6OZ-FGJB", 8: "B-12Va2DQ96", 9: "CB3e-QHAx5e", 10: "CI29bFllEBm", 11: "B1enhruHg9i"};
var galleryID;
function on(ima) {
  img = ima.id;
  document.getElementById("instagram-embed").src = "https://www.instagram.com/p/" + img + "/embed?utm_source=ig_embedembed/captioned/";
  document.getElementById("overlay").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementbyId("container").style.backgroundColor = "black";
  document.getElementById("container").style.zIndex = "2";
  getID();
}
```

Everything seems to work fine aside from the function below

```
function getID() {
var i = 0;
while(!(img == gallery[i])){
i++;
}
galleryID = i;
}
```

The value of galleryID just won't change from undefined.
I've checked the equality comparison statement separately and it seems to be working ok, giving the right true and false outputs.

I'm trying to have the while loop go through the gallery[] array items in order from 0 until it finds the item of which the data matches the data stored in the img variable. Then I want this number (the number of the index in gallery[] that represents the array item that has the same as the data in variable img) stored in the galleryID variable.

Here's the HTML for the relevant section in case it helps

```
    <div class="imggrid">
    <figure><img src="square_billie330.jpg" class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CIBf-QSFMZD"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_octopus330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CFfihZ0BxQo"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_fruits330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CDUNuwvgB7N"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_coo330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CByDTh8gUWa"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_bucky330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CB3i7NoA-IK"></figure>
    <figure><img src="squareamy330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CKSEJG9rlJn"></figure>
    <figure><img src="Tennents.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CEHrD8yAFXn"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_biggie330.jpg" class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CIY6OZ-FGJB"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_tupac330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="B-12Va2DQ96"></figure>
    <figure><img src="MD.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CB3e-QHAx5e"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_paul330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CI29bFllEBm"></figure>
    <figure><img src="bucky.jpg" class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="B1enhruHg9i"></figure>
    </div>
```

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: The function getID() is returning the right values, the only problem is it isn't being stored in galleryID.

Comment: var galleryID = 0;

Comment: Did it not solve your problem?

Comment: No unfortunately not, but thanks all the same. getID() is returning the right values but galleryID is still staying undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correct this time, you are trying to get the id of an image which has a unique code. If I we are to solve the error in the code you have written, try the code below.

```js
var img;
var gallery = {0: "CIBf-QSFMZD", 1: "CFfihZ0BxQo", 2: "CDUNuwvgB7N", 3: "CByDTh8gUWa", 4: "CB3i7NoA-IK", 5: "CKSEJG9rlJn", 6: "CEHrD8yAFXn", 7: "CIY6OZ-FGJB", 8: "B-12Va2DQ96", 9: "CB3e-QHAx5e", 10: "CI29bFllEBm", 11: "B1enhruHg9i"};
var galleryID;
function on(ima) {
  img = ima.id;
  var galleryID = getID();
  console.log(galleryID);
}
function getID() {
    var i = 0;
    while(gallery[i]){
        if(gallery[i] == img){
          return i;
        }
        i++;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="imggrid">
    <figure><img src="square_billie330.jpg" class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CIBf-QSFMZD"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_octopus330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CFfihZ0BxQo"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_fruits330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CDUNuwvgB7N"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_coo330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CByDTh8gUWa"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_bucky330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CB3i7NoA-IK"></figure>
    <figure><img src="squareamy330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CKSEJG9rlJn"></figure>
    <figure><img src="Tennents.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CEHrD8yAFXn"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_biggie330.jpg" class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CIY6OZ-FGJB"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_tupac330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="B-12Va2DQ96"></figure>
    <figure><img src="MD.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CB3e-QHAx5e"></figure>
    <figure><img src="square_paul330.jpg"  class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="CI29bFllEBm"></figure>
    <figure><img src="bucky.jpg" class="galleryimg" onclick="on(this);" id="B1enhruHg9i"></figure>
    </div>
```

What I have done in the `getID()` function is that, I am looping through every item in the object until we finally find the matching id and we return it. Then we assign that value to the `galleryID` in the `on()` function. You can test out the snippet I have provided. Hope it works!

Just a tip I can give you is that its better to start using [ES6](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp) standards in your code. You can use const and let keywords for better use of variable scope. Moreover lots of other features are available too.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Whitesmiths_style

Comment: @MisterJojo I would like to apologize if you have misunderstood. I submitted an edit in your answer by using the "tidy" option in the code snippet editor. As far as I know [here are the coding conventions in JS](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_conventions.asp). Anyways preferences matter over conventions for and it's not a problem. I apologize once again if you have misunderstood

Comment: No, I understood very well, you acted without knowing that there could be other styles of programming much better than that invented by K&R (and unfortunately many programmers adopted blindly). Maybe you even when you have written millions of lines of code you will have understood that this K&R style is a disaster in Managed Services.